# How do I change the cell fill color based on strings sought over two columns?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have two columns (B & C) containing names, but I'm looking to make sure certain words are flagged for review by changing the cell fill color.

It seems I'm not much familiar with VBA anymore, but I'm having to dabble some to get a much needed macro to work. Like I said above, I have two columns (B & C) containing names, but I'm looking to make sure certain words are flagged for review by changing the cell fill color. The words I'm looking for are "hope" and "trust", and they're likely a part of some values.

```
Sub FindTrustHope()

Dim B As Long, C As Long, i As Long
Dim findTrust As String
Dim findHope As String
B = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
C = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
findTrust = "trust"
findHope = "hope"
    For i = B To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "B") = findTrust Or Cells(i, "B") = findHope Then
        Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    If Cells(i, "C") = findTrust Or Cells(i, "C") = findHope Then
        Cells(i, "C").Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this require VBA? You can do this with Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Agree with @tigeravatar that you can use Conditional Formatting.

Comment: This macro will be used across multiple excel spreadsheets, which we receive weekly. Conditional Formatting may work, but won't I have to set that up in each new spreadsheet?

Comment: The code above works for me. Nothing happens for you if run it?

Comment: No, the code above doesn't work for me unless the cell only contains "trust" or "hope". I need to change the cell fill when "trust" or "hope" is a part of the cell's value (which is why I thought coding for a string would be ideal). For instance, if the cell value is "Bob Hope", the cell should change to red, but it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should do the trick for you.

```
Sub FindTrustHope()

Dim B As Long, C As Long, i As Long
Dim findTrust As String
Dim findHope As String
B = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
C = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
findTrust = "trust"
findHope = "hope"
    For i = B To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(Cells(i, "B"), findTrust) > 0 Or InStr(Cells(i, "B"), findHope) > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "B").Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    If InStr(Cells(i, "C"), findTrust) > 0 Or InStr(Cells(i, "C"), findHope) > 0 Then
        Cells(i, "C").Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```